# Boto3 ec2.instancesCollection infinite loop in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to get a list of all private ip addresses of my EC2 instances on Lambda. My problem is that locally it works just fine, I get them all, but when I run it on Lambda it stops right at the loop and it doesn't throw any error in Cloud

```
import boto3
import botocore

def print_hello(event, context):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id="id",
        aws_secret_access_key="key",
        region_name="region"
        )
    try:
        ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
        for instance in ec2.instances.all():
            print(instance.private_ip_address)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": ""
    }
```

As I mentioned, locally, it works just fine, I get all of them printed. When I put it up on Lambda, it times out after 9 seconds throwing no error at all. I've tried writting some prints in the code and figured that it stops right at the line

```
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
```

I thought that it might skip it in case it's empty, but it does not go past the for. I thought that maybe the print is empty, but I tried with a print(1) and it doesn't print absolutely anything inside the for either. I thought that maybe ec2.instances.all() is not iterable or some weird type, but it's ec2.instancesCollection(ec2.ServiceResource(), ec2.Instance) as it's supposed to be.

The output from CloudWatch is this:

```
START RequestId: abc Version: $LATEST
REPORT RequestId: abc   Duration: 9009.47 ms    Billed Duration: 9000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 34 MB  
Task timed out after 9.01 seconds
```

At this point I've got no idea what might cause it to work locally but not on Lambda.

Comment: Is the lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB you're a life saver. It was indeed in a VPC

Answer (score 1):

You need to either remove it from the VPC (if it doesn't really need VPC access) or deploy it only to VPC subnets with a route to a NAT Gateway.